# Call to SOAP API RequestRecipientToken fails with Unspecified_Error

Tags: docusignapi

I am able to successfully create an envelope through the SOAP API (integrating via .NET WCF) however calls to RequestRecipientToken fail with error message "Unspecified_Error". Calls to the REST API v2 for the same parameters (as much as they can be the same ... API is slightly different) are successful.

Unfortunately the only type of tracing I have been able to perform is creation of a trace file ... tried to use fiddler to monitor WCF but encryption made that unsuccessful.

The request recorded to the trace is:

```
&lt;E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"&gt;
&lt;System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"&gt;
&lt;EventID&gt;0&lt;/EventID&gt;
&lt;Type&gt;3&lt;/Type&gt;
&lt;SubType Name="Information"&gt;0&lt;/SubType&gt;
&lt;Level&gt;8&lt;/Level&gt;
&lt;TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-04T22:27:34.5571547Z" /&gt;
&lt;Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" /&gt;
&lt;Correlation ActivityID="{742449ea-863a-42a4-9c69-c5a92111e005}" /&gt;
&lt;Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="900" ThreadID="12" /&gt;
&lt;Channel /&gt;
&lt;Computer&gt;OFFICE&lt;/Computer&gt;
&lt;/System&gt;
&lt;ApplicationData&gt;
&lt;TraceData&gt;
&lt;DataItem&gt;
&lt;MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2014-03-04T17:27:34.5381536-05:00" Source="ServiceLevelSendRequest" Type="System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter+OperationFormatterMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace"&gt;
&lt;HttpRequest&gt;
&lt;Method&gt;POST&lt;/Method&gt;
&lt;QueryString&gt;&lt;/QueryString&gt;
&lt;WebHeaders&gt;
&lt;X-DocuSign-Authentication&gt;&lt;DocuSignCredentials&gt;&lt;Username&gt;***masked***&lt;/Username&gt;&lt;Password&gt;***masked***&lt;/Password&gt;&lt;IntegratorKey&gt;***masked***&lt;/IntegratorKey&gt;&lt;/DocuSignCredentials&gt;&lt;/X-DocuSign-Authentication&gt;
&lt;VsDebuggerCausalityData&gt;uIDPo7AOX0T1NXpIuAZgXjCci+8AAAAARJHtwKjn1kmg8J+ExYSKzCUDuOHpcnlBijkOggov/WUACQAA&lt;/VsDebuggerCausalityData&gt;
&lt;/WebHeaders&gt;
&lt;/HttpRequest&gt;
&lt;s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"&gt;
&lt;s:Header&gt;
&lt;Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"&gt;http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/RequestRecipientToken&lt;/Action&gt;
&lt;/s:Header&gt;
&lt;s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
&lt;RequestRecipientToken xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"&gt;
&lt;EnvelopeID&gt;200761a7-1387-492b-a4e7-46ef6832d794&lt;/EnvelopeID&gt;
&lt;ClientUserID&gt;1&lt;/ClientUserID&gt;
&lt;Username&gt;***masked***&lt;/Username&gt;
&lt;Email&gt;***masked***&lt;/Email&gt;
&lt;AuthenticationAssertion&gt;
&lt;AssertionID&gt;b0ae70e3-864b-4be0-88c6-82c0b7c7f43f&lt;/AssertionID&gt;
&lt;AuthenticationInstant&gt;2014-03-04T17:27:34.5261529-05:00&lt;/AuthenticationInstant&gt;
&lt;AuthenticationMethod&gt;Password&lt;/AuthenticationMethod&gt;
&lt;SecurityDomain&gt;***masked***&lt;/SecurityDomain&gt;
&lt;/AuthenticationAssertion&gt;
&lt;ClientURLs&gt;&lt;/ClientURLs&gt;
&lt;/RequestRecipientToken&gt;
&lt;/s:Body&gt;
&lt;/s:Envelope&gt;
&lt;/MessageLogTraceRecord&gt;
&lt;/DataItem&gt;
&lt;/TraceData&gt;
&lt;/ApplicationData&gt;
&lt;/E2ETraceEvent&gt;
```

The response recorded to the trace is:

```
&lt;E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"&gt;
&lt;System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"&gt;
&lt;EventID&gt;0&lt;/EventID&gt;
&lt;Type&gt;3&lt;/Type&gt;
&lt;SubType Name="Information"&gt;0&lt;/SubType&gt;
&lt;Level&gt;8&lt;/Level&gt;
&lt;TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-03-04T22:27:37.1393024Z" /&gt;
&lt;Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" /&gt;
&lt;Correlation ActivityID="{742449ea-863a-42a4-9c69-c5a92111e005}" /&gt;
&lt;Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="900" ThreadID="12" /&gt;
&lt;Channel /&gt;
&lt;Computer&gt;OFFICE&lt;/Computer&gt;
&lt;/System&gt;
&lt;ApplicationData&gt;
&lt;TraceData&gt;
&lt;DataItem&gt;
&lt;MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2014-03-04T17:27:37.1383024-05:00" Source="ServiceLevelReceiveReply" Type="System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace"&gt;
&lt;HttpResponse&gt;
&lt;StatusCode&gt;InternalServerError&lt;/StatusCode&gt;
&lt;StatusDescription&gt;Internal Server Error&lt;/StatusDescription&gt;
&lt;WebHeaders&gt;
&lt;Vary&gt;Accept-Encoding&lt;/Vary&gt;
&lt;Strict-Transport-Security&gt;max-age=7776000; includeSubDomains&lt;/Strict-Transport-Security&gt;
&lt;Content-Encoding&gt;&lt;/Content-Encoding&gt;
&lt;Connection&gt;Keep-Alive&lt;/Connection&gt;
&lt;Content-Length&gt;661&lt;/Content-Length&gt;
&lt;Cache-Control&gt;private&lt;/Cache-Control&gt;
&lt;Content-Type&gt;text/xml; charset=utf-8&lt;/Content-Type&gt;
&lt;Date&gt;Tue, 04 Mar 2014 22:28:32 GMT&lt;/Date&gt;
&lt;/WebHeaders&gt;
&lt;/HttpResponse&gt;
&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"&gt;
&lt;soap:Header&gt;
&lt;wsa:Action&gt;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault&lt;/wsa:Action&gt;
&lt;wsa:MessageID&gt;urn:uuid:fc236ae1-d415-422c-963f-12bae42b0408&lt;/wsa:MessageID&gt;
&lt;wsa:RelatesTo&gt;urn:uuid:13ac02ae-a7df-4709-b429-1da698317c34&lt;/wsa:RelatesTo&gt;
&lt;wsa:To&gt;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous&lt;/wsa:To&gt;
&lt;wsse:Security&gt;
&lt;wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-fafec7b1-7e35-415b-a72e-80685b8747bd"&gt;
&lt;wsu:Created&gt;2014-03-04T22:28:32Z&lt;/wsu:Created&gt;
&lt;wsu:Expires&gt;2014-03-04T22:33:32Z&lt;/wsu:Expires&gt;
&lt;/wsu:Timestamp&gt;
&lt;/wsse:Security&gt;
&lt;/soap:Header&gt;
&lt;soap:Body&gt;
&lt;soap:Fault&gt;
&lt;faultcode xmlns=""&gt;soap:Server&lt;/faultcode&gt;
&lt;faultstring xmlns=""&gt;Unspecified_Error&lt;/faultstring&gt;
&lt;faultactor xmlns=""&gt;https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx&lt;/faultactor&gt;
&lt;detail xmlns=""&gt;
&lt;ErrorCode xmlns="missing in Web.Config"&gt;1&lt;/ErrorCode&gt;
&lt;ErrorReason xmlns="missing in Web.Config"&gt;An Error Occurred.&lt;/ErrorReason&gt;
&lt;/detail&gt;
&lt;/soap:Fault&gt;
&lt;/soap:Body&gt;
&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;
&lt;/MessageLogTraceRecord&gt;
&lt;/DataItem&gt;
&lt;/TraceData&gt;
&lt;/ApplicationData&gt;
&lt;/E2ETraceEvent&gt;
```

Comment: Sorry folks ... the trace is not displaying the way it did in the preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is likely being caused by the fact that you're not including child elements within the `<ClientURLs>` element. DocuSign needs to know where to redirect the browser for each possible outcome of the signing session -- it uses the URLs that you specify within `<ClientURLs>` for that purpose.

Here's an example of a successful **RequestRecipientToken** request (I've used "http://www.cnn.com" as a placeholder value for each URL, for demonstration purposes here only):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:RequestRecipientToken>
         <ns:EnvelopeID>9c1897c0-f26c-48de-994f-db9aa07eb832</ns:EnvelopeID>
         <ns:ClientUserID>1234</ns:ClientUserID>
         <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
         <ns:Username>John Doe</ns:Username>
         <ns:Email>johnsemail@outlook.com</ns:Email>
         <ns:AuthenticationAssertion>
            <ns:AssertionID>pn2</ns:AssertionID>
            <ns:AuthenticationInstant>2014-03-04T13:50:37-07:00</ns:AuthenticationInstant>
            <ns:AuthenticationMethod>PaperDocuments</ns:AuthenticationMethod>
            <ns:SecurityDomain>docusignhq.com</ns:SecurityDomain>
         </ns:AuthenticationAssertion>
         <ns:ClientURLs>
            <ns:OnSigningComplete>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnSigningComplete>
            <ns:OnViewingComplete>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnViewingComplete>
            <ns:OnCancel>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnCancel>
            <ns:OnDecline>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnDecline>
            <ns:OnSessionTimeout>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnSessionTimeout>
            <ns:OnTTLExpired>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnTTLExpired>
            <ns:OnException>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnException>
            <ns:OnAccessCodeFailed>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnAccessCodeFailed>
            <ns:OnIdCheckFailed>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnIdCheckFailed>
            <ns:OnFaxPending>http://www.cnn.com</ns:OnFaxPending>
            <ns:GenerateSignedDocumentAsynch>false</ns:GenerateSignedDocumentAsynch>
         </ns:ClientURLs>
      </ns:RequestRecipientToken>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I was mistakenly sure that I had tried also with values passed and that it didn't work. Seems to be working now with setting all onXXX return URLs. Thanks!